# How to find the line causing error in Julia?

Tags: debugging, julia

Suppose there is a script A that calls function B, both in Julia.
There are some errors in function B, which cause the script to be stopped at runtime.
Is there a neat way to find out which line is causing the error?

It does not make any sense, to have to put messages like println manually in each line to find out upto which line the code survives, and in which line error happens.

Edit: I am using Linux Red Hat 4.1.2 and Julia version 0.3.6. directly. With no IDE.

Comment: Version of Julia, OS info, and any IDE info might be needed here. I'm running Julia v0.3.10 on Ubuntu 14.04 and whether I run Julia at the REPL or through Juno, the error message always informs me which line number triggered the error...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Reading the backtrace:

```
juser@juliabox:~$ cat foo.jl
# line 1 empty comment
foo() = error("This is line 2")
foo() # line 3

juser@juliabox:~$ julia foo.jl
ERROR: This is line 2
 in foo at /home/juser/foo.jl:2
 in include at ./boot.jl:245
 in include_from_node1 at loading.jl:128
 in process_options at ./client.jl:285
 in _start at ./client.jl:354
while loading /home/juser/foo.jl, in expression starting on line 3
```

This lines `in foo at /home/juser/foo.jl:2 ... while loading /home/juser/foo.jl, in expression starting on line 3` reads as: "there was an error at line `2` in `/home/juser/foo.jl` file ... while loading `/home/juser/foo.jl`, in expression starting on line `3`"

Looks pretty clear to me!

**Edit:** `/home/juser/foo.jl:2` means; file: `/home/juser/foo.jl`, line number: `2`.

Also you could use `@show` macro instead of `println` function for debugging purposes:

```
julia> println(1 < 5 < 10)
true

julia> @show 1 < 5 < 10
(1<5<10) => true
true
```

Comment: I am not sure I got your point :-). To make sure, do you mean that  the 2 in "foo.jl:2" is the line number?

Comment: @user25004 indeed that's precisely what I meant! I've updated my answer. Beware that currently there is an issue with line number reporting, when using macros, as they expand into more code: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/1334